# Ajuda configuração PHP Debug Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, debug, visual-studio-code

utilizo docker, gostaria de debugar meu código PHP, através do plugin "PHP Debug" do Visual Studio Code, porém, estou encontrando problemas na hora de debugar, com o Netbeans funciona.

Segue minhas configurações:

> PHP version: 7.0
>       XDebug version: 2.5.0
>       Adapter version: Visual Studio Code 1.13.0
>
> ```
> Your launch.json:
>
> {
> "version": "0.2.0",
> "configurations": [
> {
> "name": "Listen for XDebug",
> "type": "php",
> "request": "launch",
> "port": 9000,
> "stopOnEntry": true,
> "localSourceRoot": "/home/alisson/projetos/g-mus-dev",
> "serverSourceRoot": "/home/developer/workdir"
> },
> {
> "name": "Launch currently open script",
> "type": "php",
> "request": "launch",
> "program": "${file}",
> "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
> "port": 9000
> }
> ]
> }
>
> XDebug php.ini config:
>
> zend_extension=xdebug.so
> xdebug.remote_enable=on
> xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
> xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
> xdebug.remote_port=9000
> ```

Alguém tem alguma dúvida do que possa ser?

Comment: Qual é o problema? o plugin da erro e fecha o editor de texto? o debug não para nos break points?